# unable to start app from Appium Desktop app. Got an error during apksigner execution

Tags: automation, appium, appium-android

An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not sign with default certificate. Original error spawn ENOTDIR

I am trying to start an android app using Appium Desktop app. Appium server shows the following error log;

> Starting '/home/santoshpc/Android/Sdk/build-tools/28.0.3/apksigner'
>   with args
>   '["sign","--key","/tmp/.mount_AppiumGDrtg1/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-adb/keys/testkey.pk8","--cert","/tmp/.mount_AppiumGDrtg1/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-adb/keys/testkey.x509.pem","/tmp/.mount_AppiumGDrtg1/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-server/apks/appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk"]'
>   [ADB] Got an error during apksigner execution: Command
>   '/home/santoshpc/Android/Sdk/build-tools/28.0.3/apksigner sign --key
>   /tmp/.mount_AppiumGDrtg1/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-adb/keys/testkey.pk8
>   --cert /tmp/.mount_AppiumGDrtg1/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-adb/keys/testkey.x509.pem
>   /tmp/.mount_AppiumGDrtg1/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-server/apks/appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk'
>   exited with code 1 [ADB] apksigner stderr: Exception in thread "main"
>   java.nio.file.FileSystemException:
>   /tmp/.mount_AppiumGDrtg1/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-server/apks/appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk:
>   Read-only file system [ADB]   at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91)
>   [ADB]     at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
>   [ADB]     at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
>   [ADB]     at sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.move(UnixCopyFile.java:447) [ADB]
>     at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.move(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:262)
>   [ADB]     at java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1395) [ADB]  at
>   com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.sign(ApkSignerTool.java:342) [ADB]
>     at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.main(ApkSignerTool.java:89)
>   [ADB]  [ADB] Cannot use apksigner tool for signing. Defaulting to
>   sign.jar. Original error: Command
>   '/home/santoshpc/Android/Sdk/build-tools/28.0.3/apksigner sign --key
>   /tmp/.mount_AppiumGDrtg1/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-adb/keys/testkey.pk8
>   --cert /tmp/.mount_AppiumGDrtg1/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-adb/keys/testkey.x509.pem
>   /tmp/.mount_AppiumGDrtg1/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-server/apks/appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk'
>   exited with code 1; StdErr: Exception in thread "main"
>   java.nio.file.FileSystemException:
>   /tmp/.mount_AppiumGDrtg1/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-server/apks/appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidTest.apk:
>   Read-only file system [ADB]   at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91)
>   [ADB]     at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
>   [ADB]     at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
>   [ADB]     at sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.move(UnixCopyFile.java:447) [ADB]
>     at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.move(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:262)
>   [ADB]     at java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1395) [ADB]  at
>   com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.sign(ApkSignerTool.java:342) [ADB]
>     at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.main(ApkSignerTool.java:89)
>   [ADB]  [ADB] Resigning apk. [UiAutomator2] Deleting UiAutomator2
>   session [UiAutomator2] Deleting UiAutomator2 server session [WD Proxy]
>   Matched '/' to command name 'deleteSession' [UiAutomator2] Did not get
>   confirmation UiAutomator2 deleteSession worked; Error was:
>   UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing
>   the command. Original error: Trying to proxy a session command without
>   session id [ADB] Running
>   '/home/santoshpc/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s
>   0123456789ABCDEF shell am force-stop eu.niko.smart.naswi.main'
>   [Logcat] Stopping logcat capture [ADB] Removing forwarded port socket
>   connection: 8200  [ADB] Running
>   '/home/santoshpc/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s
>   0123456789ABCDEF forward --remove tcp:8200' [UiAutomator2] Unable to
>   remove port forward 'Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command
>   '/home/santoshpc/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s
>   0123456789ABCDEF forward --remove tcp:8200' exited with code 1';
>   Stderr: 'error: listener 'tcp:8200' not found'; Code: '1''
>   [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1552282079530
>   (11:12:59 GMT+0545 (+0545)) [MJSONWP] Encountered internal error
>   running command: Error: Could not sign with default certificate.
>   Original error spawn ENOTDIR [MJSONWP]     at
>   ADB.apkSigningMethods.signWithDefaultCert
>   (/tmp/.mount_AppiumGDrtg1/resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-adb/lib/tools/apk-signing.js:124:13)
>   [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 9847 ms - 206 [HTTP]  [HTTP] -->
>   DELETE /wd/hub/session [HTTP] {} [HTTP] No route found. Setting
>   content type to 'text/plain' [HTTP] <-- DELETE /wd/hub/session 404 5
>   ms - 57

I have added following **DesiredCapabilities**

```
{
  "noReset": true,
  "automationName": "uiautomator2",
  "appPackage": "myapp package name",
  "appActivity": "my app activity name",
  "deviceName": "My device",
  "platformName": "android"
}
```

Appium Desktop version: 1.11.1
OS - ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

For me what worked is going to Appium Desktop configurations and changing the `JAVA_HOME` from

```
/usr/java/bin
```

to

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the "apk-signing.js" file residing in location `/usr/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-adb/build/lib/tools`.

**Possible Solutions:**

1. It can be permission issue. The appium is executed without root
   privilege so it cannot make the changes to the apk. Executing appium
   with root/admin privilege solves the problem. (works only if
   `apk-signing.js` is bug free)
2. It's working fine for specific appium's versions as they don't have
   bug free `apk-signing.js` like appium version 1.7.2.

This is final solution if above 2 will not work. You have to modify the file `apk-signing.js`

```
./node-v6.11.4-linux-armv7l/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-adb/build/lib/tools/apk-signing.js
```

so it would return a true even if it looks not signed. Edit file as mentioned below.

> ```
> 287 case 20:
> 288 context$1$0.prev = 20;
> 289 context$1$0.t0 = context$1$0’catch’;
> 290
> 291 _loggerJs2[‘default’].debug(“App not signed with debug cert.”);
> 292 return context$1$0.abrupt(‘return’, true);
> ```

Please check this link for editing the file and for more details.

https://discuss.appium.io/t/appium-1-7-1-canot-singin-appium-uiautomator2-server-debug-androidtest-apk/19233/4

Hope it will help.